# Has Stack Exchange changed its CDN in the last day or so?

Tags: support

I've been having some intermittent problems across the whole Stack Exchange network at work over the last day or so with CSS/JS not loading and getting raw unstyled HTML as a result.  In the past, these problems have generally involved works proxy screwing up CDN access for the affected site.

Comment: And this is just on MSE or also on other sites?

Comment: Can you check what response code (or what kind of error) you're getting for the failing resources in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @ShaneMadden if it happens again maybe.  I have firebug installed; but never used anything other than the javascript debugger.

Comment: @ShaneMadden if it's the same failure pattern as I get on some sites main html, it'll be a redirection loop at something similar to bluecoat.employername.com/gibberish

Comment: @DanNeely If that's the case, then I suspect that's a malfunction of your employer's bluecoat web filter rather than anything that we're able to fix. But definitely check if it happens again!

Comment: the redirection loop problem at least has some component associated with my profile (other users on my pc aren't affected) and by browser type (sometimes different sites have problems in different browsers, when that happens the normal and portable versions of a browser fail identically).  IT spent a day swearing at my computer when I was on vacation before admitting defeat.  Bluecoat's a blackbox to me, so there's nothing I can do on my end when it throws up.

Comment: ...I mostly asked because I've seen intermittent failure precede a total blackout when there were hosting changes and loosing access here would've been a much larger impact than most of the other sites I've had problems with before.  To the extent that if I could finagle an out of cycle hardware upgrade at the same time the pain of reinstalling everything might've been the lesser evil.

Comment: I have similar issues (raw html, slow website) since a couple days. I'm not sure how to find the detailed information about the error that you're looking for, but I have this: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT http://cdn.sstatic.net/academiameta/all.css?v=b2ab0f99e801` in the console (this was on a page on meta.academia).

Comment: Sorry for the void comment, I forgot to ping @ShaneMadden

Comment: @T.Verron The timeout is what I'm looking for, thanks!  Can you check what the `colo=` line is at http://cdn.sstatic.net/cdn-cgi/trace?

Comment: @ShaneMadden `colo=CDG`

Answer (score 2):

No changes on our end that I'm aware of. I believe we're still having issues with site access from Brazil, but that's about it.

Comment: I'm in the US, so I doubt my connection is being routed through Latin America.  If it's not a random transient, that means it's probably another manifestation of proxy problems that IT can't fix or reproduce anywhere but on my account.  Due to the amount of time reinstalling/reconfiguring would require their solution of formatting my PC and giving me a clean profile is worse than the disease.  *sigh*